# How to make the Google Maps Markets like a dynamic rectangle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to do this exact Markers in my Web Application (AirBNB reference):

[image: AirBNB Search View]

But, I'm presenting two main problems:

1st: I don't know how to make the custom marker that looks just like it.

2nd: I would like to make the width of it variable, so, If my property cost $1234 or $56, the bubble should change the size.

Can anyone help me?

I used this code that I found on the internet, but the path creates a bubble that doesn't fit the requirement.

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                labelContent: "$1234",
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 65),
                labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                labelInBackground: false,
                icon: pinSymbol('#F48600'),
                id: obj['Property']['id'],
                html: someHTML 
            });

//The responsible for making the marker look "pretty".
function pinSymbol(color) 
{
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#F48600',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 2
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of creating the symbol, if you get a copy of the image, you can try exploring the icon object for the marker options [[ref. google]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon). Set `google.maps.Icon.url` to the image.
2. The icon object specification could also lend itself to this problem too. See `google.maps.Icon.scaledSize`. This would scale your image up or down. `icon.scaledSize` needs to be a `google.maps.Size` object, so I'd try writing a custom method that returns a new size object based on your cost scale.

   ```
   var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({

     ...

     icon: {
       url: 'marker.jpg',
       scaledSize: iconSize(1234)             
     },

     ...
   });

   // a crude scale solution
   var WIDTH_RANGE = {
     min: 50, // pixels
     max: 200,
   };
   var HEIGHT_RANGE = {
     min: 20,
     max: 50
   };
   var COST_RANGE = {
     min: 0,
     max: <max cost> // dynamically set a max cost somehow
   };

   function iconSize (cost) {
     var scaleFactor = cost / (COST_RANGE.max - COST_RANGE.min);
     var width = (WIDTH_RANGE.max - WIDTH_RANGE.min) * scaleFactor + WIDTH_RANGE.min;
     var height = (HEIGHT_RANGE.max - HEIGHT_RANGE.min) * scaleFactor + HEIGHT_RANGE.min;

     return new google.maps.Size(width, height);
   }
   ```